# No numFmt in Styles.xml

Tags: excel, openxml, xlsx

I am analyzing an OpenXML Excel file. I check the styles.xml, I find many entries like this:

```
<xf numFmtId="0" [..]>
```

However, there are no `<numFmt>` element in the styles.xml file at all. In such a case, how can I determine the number format for that style?

Answer (score 4):

If the user applies a custom number format then the `styles.xml` file will contain `numFmt` elements like this with a `numFmtId` and `formatCode`:

```
<numFmts count="1">
  <numFmt 
    numFmtId="165" 
    formatCode="0.000"/>
</numFmts>
```

The `numFmtId` is then used in the `<xf>` element to reference the number format.

However, if the user applies a standard or built-in format such as `0.00` then a `numFmt` element isn't written. The `<xf>` element still contains a `numFmtId` but it refers to a built-in format that isn't stored in the file.

Number format ids less than 164 (but most often in the range 0-50) represent builtin formats.

[Here is a list](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#format-set-num-format) of some of the built-in formats form the XlsxWriter documentation.